# Do PHP printer functions work on a live server?

Tags: php

I used printer functions in PHP to print data. It works on my local development server (localhost),
but it is not working in a live environment.
Is it possible to use the PHP printer functions on a live web server?

Comment: Weird question, but a physical printer functions (i.e a printer device) or printing as in output (echo and print_r) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No external libraries are needed to
>   build this extension.

Source: www.php.net

Check to make sure that if you are using short tags eg `<?=...?>`, then you should allow short tags on public server also. This is mostly the case we do not consider.